# How many round trips to the database Flyway is doing to determine which migration have to be run?

Tags: database, sqlite, migration, flyway

I have 10 migration scripts (V1 to V10) in my folder "db/migration". When I previously launched my application the 5 first were run. 
So, next time I will launch it I expect that the script from V6 to V10 will be run.
My question is:

**How Flyway determines which scripts have to be run?**

If it has to check information in the database:

**How many round trip to the database are necessary?**

It is really important for me that the number of round trip is the minimum possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flyway executes one roundtrip per migration. This means that every time it applies a migration it will then query the schema_version table again before applying the next one (this is necessary to support multiple nodes attempting to migrate the DB in parallel)